# Rock, Paper, Scissors: Trying to keep score using C#

Tags: c#

So, everything is working fine. The game loops and everything, but when the person no longer wants to play the game again is only shows the score for that one round and not the others. It is supposed to display something like this: Player 1 wins 3 rounds, Computer wins 2 rounds, Draw 4 round. But it What am I missing?

```
//RPSGame
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class RPSGame
{
    private string playerMove;
    private string computerMove;
    private int draws;
    private int playerWins;
    private int computerWins;
    // Constructor to Create a New Rock, Paper, Scissors Game Object
    public RPSGame()
    {
        //Setting up game by asking user for their response

        Console.WriteLine("Hey do you want to play a game? y or n: ");
        playerMove = Console.ReadLine();
        if (playerMove == "N" || playerMove == "n")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Awe ok, No game for you then! Here is your score: ");
            }
            else if (playerMove == "Y" || playerMove == "y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pick R for Rock, S for Scissors or P for Paper");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Response, y or n only!");
    }
    public int Draws
    {
        get { return draws; }
    }
    public int PlayerWins
    {
        get { return playerWins; }
    }
    public int ComputerWins
    {
        get { return computerWins; }
    }
    public string PlayerMove // Property to set or return player's move
    {
        get
        {
            return playerMove;
        }
        set
        {
            playerMove = value.ToUpper();
        }
    }
    public string ComputerMove // Property to return computer's move
    {
        get
        {
   
            return computerMove;
        }
    }
    public void GetComputerMove()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int move = rand.Next(3) + 1; // Random number from 1 to 3
        if (move == 1)
            computerMove = "R";
        
        else if (move == 2)
            computerMove = "P";
        
        else
            computerMove = "S";
    }
    public string DisplayMoves()
    {
        string moves = "";
        string cMove = "", pMove = "";
    bool invalidMove = false;
        if (playerMove == "R")
            pMove = "Rock";
        else if (playerMove == "P")
            pMove = "Paper";
        else if (playerMove == "S")
            pMove = "Scissors";
else
        {
            pMove = "\nInvalid entry...Must enter an R, P, or S.";
            invalidMove = true;
        }
        if (computerMove == "R")
            cMove = "Rock";
        else if (computerMove == "P")
            cMove = "Paper";
        else
            cMove = "Scissors";
        if (invalidMove)
            moves = pMove;
        else
            moves = ("\nPlayer's Move: " + pMove +
            "\nComputer's Move: " + cMove + "\n");
        return moves;
    }
    public string DetermineWinner()
    {
        // R = Rock P = Paper S = Scissors
        string message = "";
        if (playerMove == computerMove)
        {
            message = ("It's a draw!");
            draws++;
        }
        else if (playerMove == "R" && computerMove == "P")
        {
            message = ("Computer Wins! Paper Covers Rock!");
            computerWins++;
        }
        else if (playerMove == "R" && computerMove == "S")
        {
            message = "Player Wins! Rock Smashes Scissors!";
            playerWins++;
        }
        else if (playerMove == "P" && computerMove == "R")
        {
            message = "Player Wins! Paper Covers Rock!";
            playerWins++;
        }
        else if (playerMove == "P" && computerMove == "S")
        {
            message = "Computer Wins! Scissors Cut Paper!";
            computerWins++;
        }
        else if (playerMove == "S" && computerMove == "R")
        {
            message = "Computer Wins! Rock Smashes Scissors!";
            computerWins++;
        }
        else if (playerMove == "S" && computerMove == "P")
        {
            message = "Player Wins! Sciccors Cut Paper!";
            playerWins++;
        }
        return message;
    }
    public string ShowStats()
    {
    string stats = ("Draws: " + draws + "\n" +
    "Player Wins: " + playerWins + "\n" +
    "Computer Wins: " + computerWins + "\n");
        return stats;
    }
}





//Program
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool gameLoop = true;
            string answer;
            while (gameLoop)
            {
                RPSGame game = new RPSGame();
                game.PlayerMove = Console.ReadLine();
                game.GetComputerMove();
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Player Move: " + game.PlayerMove);
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Move: " + game.ComputerMove);
            
 Console.WriteLine(game.DisplayMoves);
            
Console.WriteLine(game.DetermineWinner());
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------");

                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again y or n: ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                answer = Console.ReadLine();
                answer = answer.ToUpper();
                if (answer == "Y")
                {
                    gameLoop = true;
                   // Console.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    gameLoop = false;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
                
 Console.Write(game.ShowStats());
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
                }

       
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `RPSGame game = new RPSGame();` being in a while. Each iteration you create new instance of **RPSGame** and rewrite the old one. And the new instance is every time created with default values (zeroes for score)..

You need to create instance of **RPSGame** once before loop. Then it won't rewrite it in each round and will hold score data from all rounds.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I’m still very new at C# and have been trying to run my lines of code step by step as I go in order to catch any errors or bugs. Reading your explanation made so much sense, I thought I was gonna have to create a method that saved each game score or something if the sort.